# CMake statically Link ImageMagick?

Tags: cmake

currently I'm really really new to C++ and CMake, however I have a program that want's to statically Link ImageMagick, but only ImageMagick.

Mostly cause I need ImageMagick which isn't supported everywhere. I could also Clone the Source code.
Currently my CMakeList.txt is like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(envisia_worker)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# ImageMagick
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)

# Nuance
link_directories("/usr/local/lib/nuance-omnipage-csdk-lib64-19.2")

# Building
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(envisia_worker ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Nuance
include_directories("/usr/local/include/nuance-omnipage-csdk-19.2")
target_link_libraries(envisia_worker kernelapi recpdf recapiplus)

# ImageMagick
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(envisia_worker ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

However that will Link against my distributions ImageMagick 5.
Also I include other libraries they should stay dynlib, however ImageMagick should somehow be linked statically, is there any way of doing so?

Comment: I am not quite understand, what you want. `however ImageMagick should somehow be linked statically` - only **static libraries** can be *statically* linked to. Is `ImageMagick` can be built as set of static libraries? Or your problem is how to tell `find_package(ImageMagick)` to find *your own installation* of this package instead of *system-wide one*?

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, find_package found everything and I could use ImageMagick, however I thought that I could somehow link ImageMagick statically with all his dependencies cause It is really aweful to have linked against dozens of libraries and hoping that every distribution has the correct version.
But as I read more and more it's not as easy as I thought especially not for ImageMagick

Comment: So, you want to **build executable on one machine, and use it on another one**? And care that linkage to some libraries should use their **paths** (absolute or relative), because your provide them on another machine, but linkage to some other libraries (like `ImageMagick`) you want to be **name-only**, so they can be found dynamically in package-specific directories? I just want to make the question clearer.

Comment: No I want dynamic links, but ImageMagick should be linked statically, so that I don't need to install ImageMagick, just copy my binary. ;)

Comment: Probably, you found this [article](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) helpful. It describes how CMake handles `RPATH` - being compiled into executable, this is actually a search list, where libraries are searched for load executable.

Answer (score 1):

You may specify RPATH for your executable, so it will be searched *before* system directories when executable will be loaded:

```
...
# ImageMagick
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)

# Deduce directories, where ImageMagick libraries are located
set(ImageMagick_LIBRARIES_DIRS)
foreach(lib ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
    get_filename_component(dir ${lib} DIRECTORY)
    list(APPEND ImageMagick_LIBRARIES_DIRS ${dir})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES ImageMagick_LIBRARIES_DIRS)
endforeach()

# Tell CMake to set RPATH for all *futher* targets.
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES_DIRS})

... # Create targets, link them, etc.

# Install targets
install(TARGETS envisia_worker DESTINATION <...>)
```

Note, that only *installed* targets take the effect of `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` variable.

*Built* targets already have RPATH pointed to every library which target is linked to, but such targets are usually used only on current machine. It is *installed* targets which needs to be **distributable** to other machines.

More detailed description of interacting CMake and RPATH can be found [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

---

Note, that using absolute paths in RPATH for package-local libraries makes package **distributable**, but **not relocatable**: on other machines you need to have package(with its libs) *at the same location*, where it has been installed on original machine.

For make package **relocatable**, that is to allow it(with libs) to have any path on other machine, RPATH for executable should use paths, relative to `$ORIGIN` - directory with executable itself. But using this base in the `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` variable is more tricky, read [this mailing](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-January/019290.html) for more info.